# JSTL NumberFormatException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, jstl

I have a spring+hibernate application where I make a native query in my DAO layer. The query looks like the following

```
select name, amount from myTable where id=:id
```

It is clear that the selected fields are of different data types (String, Number).

In the JSP I want to print the returned result in table so I am using `foreach loop` to go through each record in the returned set.

I want to put the negative numbers between braces so I am using the following code

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${resultSet}">
                    <tr>
                        <c:forEach var="v" items="${item}" varStatus="st">
                                    <td>
                                <c:choose>
                                    <c:when test="${v != null}">
                                        <c:choose>
                                            <c:when test="${v<0}">
                                                <c:out value="(${v})"></c:out>
                                            </c:when>
                                            <c:otherwise>
                                                <c:out value="${v}"></c:out>
                                            </c:otherwise>
                                        </c:choose>
                                    </c:when>
                                    <c:otherwise>
                                        <c:out value="-"></c:out>
                                    </c:otherwise>
                                </c:choose>
                            </td>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
```

As the first item in the query is string, this code fires NumberFormateException.

I know two solutions for this problem. The first is put the braces in the SQL query but I can not use this solution as the application contains many queries and it will take a lot of time modifying all the queries.

The second solution is to use resultTransformer and convert the returned data into one Object but this is not suitable for the same previous reason.

Is there any workaround to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this ??

```
 <c:when test=${v<0}>
            <c:out value="(${v})"></c:out>
                     </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
             <c:out value="${v}"></c:out>
```

Comment: this is what I have done please check the code in my question

Comment: check the first line ${v<0} .remove those "".